# Is it possible to mimic two joints combined?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a couple of closed loop mechanisms connected in which there is rotary joint A, B and a prismatic joint C . Joint A should  mimic joint B&C combined.

something like this
A =  B + 0.5*C

Is this possible in URDF  mimic tag ? bit confused.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307392/is-it-possible-to-mimic-two-joints-combined-?/) by [BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28829/bhanukiran.chaluvadi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2018-11-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From [the documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/joint):

> The value of this joint can be computed as `value = multiplier * other_joint_value + offset`.

So no, referring to two joints is not supported right now.

You *may* be able to do something with [transmission](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/Transmission), but I'm not sure.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1